# How do I have multiple Tailwind CSS output when using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, tailwind-css, webpacker

I use Webpacker to bundle my css. I would like to have 2 different CSS builds using 2 different Tailwind configs, outputting into `static_page.css` and a `dashboard.css` respectively.

Comment: Any joy with this? I'm trying to do similar.

Comment: Would love to find a solution to this as well!